# Trying to install Guest Additions in Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to **install Guest Additions**, the guest SO is Fedora 24 and the host SO is Windows 7.

I'm doing this to fix the screen resolution in Fedora because the maximum I can get is 1024x768, while in Windows I have 1366x768.

**The problem is that when I try to install Guest Additions I get this**:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.26 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.0.26 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules[  OK  ]
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules[  OK  ]
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules[  OK  ]
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules[  OK  ]
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules
Building the main Guest Additions module[FALLÓ]
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions[  OK  ]
Press Return to close this window...
```

So everything is fine except Building the main Guest Additions module

This is in **/var/log/vboxadd-install.log**:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/5.0.26/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxguest-5.0.26

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/5.0.26/build......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/5.0.26/build/make.log for more information.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
grep: /lib/modules/4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.8.4-200.fc24.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvar-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wno-declaration-after-statement -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangli
```

So I guess that it can't find `include/generated/autoconf.h` or `include/config/auto.conf` files, what can I do?

I've already done:

```
yum install dkms binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing occurs on newest version of VirtualBox (5.1.8) with Windows 10 as host system. With the same error as OP I didn't managed to get it working on 4.8.6 kernel, but when I returned to older 4.5.5 one, installation went smooth and everything works as expected (tested resizing window and shared clipboard). For now, I am sticking to older kernel.

Comment: I solved the problem by upgrading from `5.1.8` to `5.1.14`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar issue, with Fedora 24 on kernel 4.8.7, with Virtual Box 5.0.28 from a Windows 8.1 host.

I got it working by:

- Removing the current guest additions (`VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall` in the CD directory)
- Installing Virtual Box 5.1.8
- Checking that `dkms, gcc, kernel-devel, kernel-header` are the latest version
- Then finally installing guest additions 5.1.8 from the ISO that comes with VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall VirtualBox-5.0 and install VirtualBox-5.1

Comment: Will this solve the problem that's described, or is it just a general statement?